# Is it possible to create a function in Haskell that operates on a set of types?

Tags: haskell, abstract-data-type

I have been searching google for a while, but was not able to find an answer:

Say I have Tree ADT that is polymorphic, a base payload sum type and two extention sum types:

```
--Base.hs
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a] | Empty
data BasePayload = BaseA String | BaseB Int

--Extention1.hs
data Extention1 = Ext1A String String | Ext1B Int

--Extention2.hs
data Extention2 = B | A
```

I cannot modify the base type, and I do not know if and how many extention types are used at compile time. Is it possible to create functions that work like this:

```
--Base.hs
type GeneralTree = Tree SomeBoxType

transform :: Tree (SomeBoxType (any | BasePayload)) -> Tree (SomeBoxType any)

--Extention1.hs
transform :: Tree (SomeBoxType (any | Extention1)) -> Tree (SomeBoxType any)

--Extention2.hs
transform :: Tree (SomeBoxType (any | Extention2)) -> Tree (SomeBoxType any)
```

Is something like this possible? When I searched I found GADT, which is not what I need and DataKinds and TypeFamilies, which I did not  understand 100%, but dont think will help here. Is that Row Polymorphism?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `SomeBoxType`?

Comment: That is the question, is there some sort of Box type that allows this behavior

Comment: What's `Tree (SomeBoxType (any | Extention2))` again? What do you mean by `any | Extention2` there? It's a function signature, not a data declaration, and you're using data declaration syntax here.

Comment: And how do you _intend to use all of this_? That's generally the most useful piece of information.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz basicly "This type can hold anything plus optionally the types from `Extention2`"

@leftaroundabout A plugin based tree transforming application, the tree represents data that is in the payload. Depending on context, I need additional data that can be transformed to base data, so I have a plugin that takes the extended definition and transforms all extra data to the base data. As the base program should not be recompiled for every setting I cannot modify the base ADT, basicy it is a compiler

Comment: If it can hold anything, then it can also hold Extention2, no? Why do you need to single it out? And to the comment above, why can't you just parametrize your tree type on that additional data? You need to build everything together anyway, no?

Comment: Just to show that after the transformation it is not left in there, you are right, it should be `transform:: Tree (SomeBoxType any) -> Tree (SomeBoxType (any without Extention2))` I do not care about the types that much, because this happens at runtime anyway. In theory `any -> any` would be also fine, I just want to pattern match out the Extention2 types

Comment: Well "any" type wrapper, while possible, is not very useful since you erase all type information that way. "Any without extensions" isn't very meaningful either. Again, why not `Tree AnnotatedData -> Tree BaseData`? You can't "pattern match" on any value, that's essentially dynamic typing you're asking for.

Comment: Because the two plugins could be used together, so it would be `Tree AnnotatedData1and2 -> Tree AnnotatedData2` and this with all possible permutations. Not possible, because I want to add plugins later on without modifying every other plugin

Comment: Well if all of those can be combined into BaseData, you just need a class with a `class CombinesWithBase where combine :: a -> BaseData -> BaseData`. Then you can create a polywrapper for the extensions: `newtype Polyextension = forall a. CombinesWithBase a => Polyextension a`, make it an instance of `CombineWithBase`: `instance CombineWithBase Polyextension where combine (Polyextension a) b = combine a b`, and lastly store those in a list: `data ComplexData = CD BaseData [Polyextension]`. This is supposedly an antipattern (that's why it's not an answer), but has worked for me before.

Comment: You may want to read "Data types à la carte". I suspect that's what you're reaching toward.

Comment: @dfeuer I think you are right, but currently I understand only half of the paper and can't transfer the technique to my tree example. I have to reread it a few times

Comment: You should also read some of what Oleg Kiselyov has written about [tagless final style](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/index.html) for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you just want a `Functor` instance. Thus:

```
instance Functor Tree where
    fmap f (Node x children) = Node (f x) (fmap (fmap f) children)
    fmap f Empty = Empty
```

Now `fmap` can be given any of these types:

```
fmap :: (Either any BasePayload -> any) -> Tree (Either any BasePayload) -> Tree any
fmap :: (Either any Extention1  -> any) -> Tree (Either any Extention1 ) -> Tree any
fmap :: (Either any Extention2  -> any) -> Tree (Either any Extention2 ) -> Tree any
```

As an aside, I find the `Empty` constructor very suspicious. What's the difference between `Node 0 []` and `Node 0 [Empty]` for example? Is `Node 0 [Empty, Empty]` a sensible value to have at all? Consider using [`Data.Tree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.2/docs/Data-Tree.html), which comes with your compiler, doesn't have this issue, and already has a `Functor` instance.